# IEnumerable Interface Causing An Error with List

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I am supposed to adjust my `InvItems` class to use the `IEnumerable` interface, but not use the `IEnumerable<>` interface. However, when I adjust the class, my `List<InvItem>` pops up with errors, and I don't understand why.

The error is :

> "the type or namespace could not be found."

I think I have to convert the List, but I'm not quite sure how (I've only found instructions for using the `IEnumerable <>` interface.) Thank you for any help!

```
public class InvItemList : IEnumerable
{
    private List<InvItem> invItems;

    public InvItemList()
    {
        invItems = new List<InvItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (InvItem in invItems)
        {
            yield return frmNewItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. What exception 2. What is `frmNewItem`?

Comment: what's `frmNewItem` ?

Comment: Form that uses the classes. I have an InvItem class, and InvItemList class, and a New Item form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for `IEnumerable` is `System.Collections` while the one for `IEnumerable<T>` is `System.Collections.Generic`.

Make sure you are referencing the correct one.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for adding escape characters.

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought too; am I using it incorrectly that you can see? 
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InventoryMaintenance
{
    public class InvItemList : IEnumerable
    {
        private List<InvItem> invItems;

        public InvItemList()
        {
            invItems = new List<InvItem>();

Comment: As you want to use `List<T>`, you have to add namespace reference `System.Collection.Generic` either. So the correct reference order may be : `using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: Or you can define InvItemList in this way: `public class InvItemList : System.Collections.IEnumerable` then there will never be any mis-referencing.

Comment: Aha, if I put in both System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic, and then define which IEnumerable I use with the class, that solves the errors! Thanks so much!

Comment: welcome~ You can try to use Resharper or StyleCop. They can provide more hints when you code in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to import `System.Collection` to get rid of *namespace could not be found* error.
2. You should probably consider using generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface instead of non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Here your code fix to make it compile:

```
public class InvItemList : IEnumerable
{
    private List<InvItem> invItems;

    public InvItemList()
    {
        invItems = new List<InvItem>();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return invItems.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I used `List<T>.GetEnumerator()` method instead od `foreach` loop, because it looks cleaner.

To implement generic `IEnumerable<T>` change class declaration and add one additional method:

```
public class InvItemList : IEnumerable<InvItem>, IEnumerable
{

    // (...)

    IEnumerator<InvItem> IEnumerable<InvItem>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return invItems.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to correct a few errors:

Add:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Correct the "foreach" statement:

```
foreach (InvItem frmNewItem in invItems)
```

So together it looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;

public class InvItem
{
}

public class InvItemList : IEnumerable
{
    private List<InvItem> invItems;

    public InvItemList()
    {
        invItems = new List<InvItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (InvItem frmNewItem in invItems)
        {
            yield return frmNewItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your foreach, I get an "Unreachable code detected" error. My InvItem class is public; researching it, the error seems to refer to the loop breaking incorrectly. But how can that be?

Comment: On what line does it show the error? I suspect not in the foreach, if you copied the above code verbatim. Although the class as it is now is not very useful. You are creating an empty list instance as a private member field, and there is no code adding any items to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I use both System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic, and then when declare the class with

```
public class InvItemList : System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

the errors resolve.